# How to code read buffer scsi command?

Tags: java, android, usb, scsi

I used [libaums](https://github.com/mjdev/libaums) to access private partition of my custom USB. Now  I want to know how to read the **Hidden area** of my USB. To access the hidden area, I know the **sector range** of hidden address for my USB, and also the **vendor specific command** (or opcode) for read and write hidden area.

So far I read [scsi command](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-3Kvs1eXMAhUKuY8KHTQfAwMQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seagate.com%2Fstaticfiles%2Fsupport%2Fdisc%2Fmanuals%2Fscsi%2F100293068a.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH-q8SLDGr2yHN-vxTym7R2y6KcYQ&sig2=HlZDQidBmCiPryk-vvZQlg&bvm=bv.122448493,d.c2I) and found out about **Read Buffer Command** has Vendor-specific mode(01h). Does anybody know how to code the read buffer command? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScsiReadHidden readHidden = new ScsiReadHidden();
readHidden.serialize();//produce an array which is readHidden.cbwBuffer.array()
int iRes = conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, readHidden.cbwBuffer.array(), 31, 2000);
iRes = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, readHidden.cswBuffer, 512, 2000);
```